# boolean if record is first 10 post of the month

Tags: mysql

i have a very tough mysql statement question.

i have a table with the following structure.

```
post_id, date_time, category_id
```

i want to sort this table by `date_time` and also to have a **true** or **false** Boolean that indicates if this record is the first 10 record of the month of each category.

for example first 10 record of Oct 2011 for category a will be true, first 10 record of the Oct 2011 for category b is also true, first 10 record of Nov 2011 for category c will be true, first 10 record of the Nov 2011 for category b is also true.

Please guide me along. thanks!

Comment: look on this  article http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#104

Answer (score 0):

You just apply query for select date_time from tablename oder by date_time desc
OR
You can do like get all the data_time field column data in array.
and apply substring logic to get the only date number.
After you can sort that according to value
and append again remaing part ..
like
10-11-2011 15:30:46
take String date=substring(0,2)
so you got 10
and String remainingDatepart=(3,length)
after you just sort according to date.
and after you can append reminingDatapart string in sorted date..
This is logic you can apply them.

Comment: i need it to be in the form of a boolean. also there are two constraints month and category.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should od the trick, I've only tested it in my head.

```
SELECT 
  s.*
  , CASE WHEN s.rank < 10 
         THEN TRUE
         ELSE FALSE
         END AS top10
FROM (
  SELECT
    t1.post_id, t1.date_time, t1.category_id
    ,CONCAT(year(t1.date_time), month(t1.date_time)) as yearmonth
    ,@prevyearmonth:= CONCAT(year(t1.date_time), month(t1.date_time)) as yearmonth
    ,CASE WHEN (@prevyearmonth = CONCAT(year(t1.date_time), month(t1.date_time))) 
          THEN @rank:= @rank + 1
          ELSE @rank:= 1
     END as rank
  FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY date_time DESC) t1
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank:= 0, @prevyearmonth:= null)
  ORDER BY date_time DESC
  ) s
/* HAVING top10 = TRUE */
ORDER BY s.date_time, s.top10
```

Comment: let me bring back to absorb this. Are you open to come out with the entire statement for me? i can pay you thru paypal for this effort. If interested please email me damian_sia@hotmail.com

Comment: @DamianSia, thanks for the suggestion, but this is the entire statement.  Is there a part that you don't understand?

Comment: actually this is only part of the entire picture. i only ask the part which i don't know how to do. do you mind providing your email or email me? @Johan

Comment: @DamianSia, I don't feel like it.

Comment: it's ok then, i will try to understand your code and play around with it. thanks!